# Multiple selects in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following basic query which I need tweaked:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY,
       PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
       USC_CODE,
       USC_DESCRIPTION
FROM ADMIN.PRODUCT_DIM
WHERE COUNTRY_CODE = 'US'
    AND usc_code IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY PRODUCT_KEY,
         PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
         USC_CODE,
         USC_DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY PRODUCT_KEY
```

What I need to list any of the `select` fields only if the there are 1 or none product_keys within `usc_code`.

So if usc 12345 has zero or 1 product only I want to see that usc, product, desc, etc. out of it.

So I'm thinking I need another select in the middle somewhere but not sure where.

Here's some sample data:

```
PRODUCT_KEY PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION     USC_CODE USC_DESCRIPTION
1000376001  B COMPLEX/C         76222    B-COMPLEX,W/C,ORAL
1000610001  OXYMETAZOLINE HCL   14200    DECONGESTANTS ALONE
1000611001  OXYMETAZOLINE HCL   14200    DECONGESTANTS ALONE
1000612001  OXYMETAZOLINE HCL   14200    DECONGESTANTS ALONE
1000613001  OXYMETAZOLINE HCL   14200    DECONGESTANTS ALONE
1000614001  OXYMETAZOLINE HCL   14200    DECONGESTANTS ALONE
1000615001  OXYMETAZOLINE HCL   78120    CRUDE/BULK MED
```

Comment: please show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Check Having count(*) clause ... if i understood your problem correctly, that's the clause you need

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Man, put those data into question ... go for 'edit question' and format data there ... or insert it as a picture

Comment: Where can we get the list of products if they doesn't appear on product_dim ?

Comment: What about `having COUNT(product_key)<2`

Comment: How would we see an USC code that had no product? As far as I can see, it wouldn't have a row in the table at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION, COUNT(*)
FROM ADMIN.PRODUCT_DIM
WHERE COUNTRY_CODE = 'US'
   AND usc_code is not null
GROUP BY PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0 OR COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY PRODUCT_KEY
```

Comment: Got an error on that code as well. Seems it doesn't like "Having" or doesn't like it in that part of the code.

Comment: dang! I'm always messing up the sequence of GROUP, HAVING and ORDER BY.. I've checked it this time

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION 

FROM ADMIN.PRODUCT_DIM

WHERE COUNTRY_CODE = 'US'
and usc_code is not null

Group By PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION
HAVING COUNT (PRODUCT_KEY) <2
Order by PRODUCT_KEY
```

Comment: It doesn't like "having". Get errors.Error: ERROR:  'SELECT PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION FROM ADMIN.PRODUCT_DIM WHERE COUNTRY_CODE = 'US' and usc_code is not null Group By PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, USC_CODE, USC_DESCRIPTION Order by PRODUCT_KEY HAVING COUNT (PRODUCT_KEY) <2'
error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           (State:HY000, Native Code: 6C)

Comment: @Jay HAVING needs to go before ORDER BY, however in this case it'll not do anything useful since you're already grouping by PRODUCT_KEY so there's only one per group to count.

Comment: Thanks. The HAVING now works. I think that will give me what I need if I use the product_id instead of the product_key because in my case product_id is the first 7 characters of the 10 byte product_key. So I am seeing counts of more than 1 if I don't use HAVING.

Comment: I edited the answer and put having in the right place, sorry for that